# CMake and custom sdk (yocto+arm) for building target applications

Tags: gcc, cmake, g++

I have received an SDK that is used to build c++/c applications for an embedded linux device. This is all new to me so some of my terminology may be wrong.

I followed their instructions and the SDK installs on my linux (ubuntu) system in /opt/. The compiler they are using appears to be **arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc**. Part of their SDK sets some environment variables, like **$CC and CPP** for compiling C/C++. The environment variables run something like **arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a (and a bunch of other flags)**.

My question is: how can I utilize this using cmakelists/cmake? I currently have an entire library and application that is built around cmake.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK should come with a toolchain file for cmake (for example named `toolchain.cmake`).

When you first call your cmake, you force it to use the SDK like this:
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/???/toolchain.cmake`.